# The area of the circle that is the limit of a sequence of circumscribed regular polygons.

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry

Let $a_n$ be the sequence of circumscribed regular polygons, such that $a_n$ is the smallest $(n+2)\operatorname{-gon}$ that circumscribes $a_{n-1}$. For example:

$a_1$ is a triangle with side length of 1.

$a_2$ is the smallest square that circumscribes $a_1$.

---

Let $b_n$ be $a_n$ with the added restriction that the polygons share a vertex.

Below is the construction of $b_7$. Note $b_7$ is only the nonagon.

[image: construction of b_7]

---

Let the [sequence of circumscribed polygons and circles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle#/media/File:Kepler_constant_inverse.svg) be $c_n$ and $c_1 = a_1$.

---

All 3 sequences monotonically increase $\land \forall n\ \operatorname{area}(a_n) \leq \operatorname{area}(b_n) \leq \operatorname{area}(c_n) \land \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \operatorname{area}(c_n)$ converges, therefore both $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \operatorname{area}(a_n)$ and $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \operatorname{area}(b_n)$ also converge.

---

Questions:

1. What does $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \operatorname{area}(a_n)$ converge to?
2. What does $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \operatorname{area}(b_n)$ converge to?

---

EDIT

Jaap Scherphuis has brought to my attention that the construction in the figure contradicts the definition of the sequence. So I changed the question to have 2 parts.

Comment: Your picture shows all the polygons sharing a vertex, but this does not match your description of each polygon being the smallest circumscribing one. For example, look a the hexagon inside the heptagon. You can move the hexagon upwards a little and it will be fully inside the heptagon, not touching any of the sides or vertices. So the heptagon is not the smallest possible circumscribing one.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I removed the picture.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

*Case $n=20$.*

[image]

*Case $n=200$.*

"Almost complete" solution :

Let $O$ be the common point to all $n$-gons. Let $OP_n$ be the side of the regular $n$-gon in the progressively thinner triangles $OP_nP_{n+1}$ one finds in the bottom right part of the figure.

The internal angle of the regular $n-gon$ is known to be :

$$\alpha_n:=\frac{(n-2)\pi}{n}\tag{1}$$

(for example, for a square $n=4$, one gets $\alpha_4=\frac{\pi}{2}$)

We will work of course on the half of these angles,

$$\beta_n:=\frac{(n-2)\pi}{2n}$$

starting from the vertical issued from point $O$ which is the angle bissector of the vertices' angles.

Let us compute the different angles in triangle $OP_nP_{n+1}$ :

From what has been obtained before :

- angle $\angle OP_{n+1}P_n = \alpha_{n+1}$ (see (1)).
- angle $\angle P_{n+1}OP_n $ is
  $$\gamma_n := \beta_{n+1} - \beta_{n}=\frac{(n-1)\pi}{2(n+1)}-\frac{(n-2)\pi}{2(n)}=\frac{\pi}{n(n+1)}$$
- angle $\angle P_{n+1}P_nO=\delta_n:=\pi-\alpha_{n+1}-\gamma_n=\frac{2n-1}{n(n+1)}\pi$

Sanity check : for $n=3$ (triangle), one finds the good angles.

Then (sines' law) : $$\frac{OP_{n+1}}{\sin \delta_n}=\frac{OP_{n}}{\sin \alpha_{n+1}}\tag{2}$$

giving the recurrence :

$$OP_{n+1}=\frac{\sin\left(\frac{2n-1}{n(n+1)}\pi\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{n-1}{n+1}\pi\right)}OP_n$$

$$OP_{n+1}=\frac{\sin\left(\frac{2n-1}{n(n+1)}\pi\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{2}{n+1}\pi\right)}OP_n\tag{3}$$

Relationship (3), starting from $OP_3=1$ (we take the initial equilateral triangle = "$3$-gon" to be unit-sided), one can get $OP_{n}$ ;

For $n \to \infty$, the infinite product obtained in this way tends to $0$ according to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=product+of+Sin%5BPi*%282*n-1%29%2F%28n%28n%2B1%29%29%5D%2F%28Sin%5BPi*2%2F%28n%2B1%29%5D%29+from+n%3D3+to+infinity). But one must cope with the fact that having the side of the regular $n$-gon $OP_n$ (which, at the limit for $n \to \infty$ is a circle), we have to divide it by $2 \sin \frac{\pi}{n}$ (which itself tends to $0$ when $n\to\infty$) in order to obtain the radius of the limit circumscribed circle. This radius uncreases very slowly : for example, it is equal to $\approx 4.7$ when $n=200$ (as can be seen on , $\approx 5.8$ when $n=300$, but it is impossible to infer from such *numerical* results whether the limit radius is finite or not.

Matlab program for the figure in the case $n=20$:

```
 clear all;close all;hold on;axis equal;
 r=1;t=pi/3;
 S=[0];nlim=20;
 for n=3:nlim
    u=r*exp(i*t);
    m=exp(i*2*angle(u));
    p=cumsum(u*m.^(0:(n-1))); % n-gon
    S=[S,p];
    k=1/(n*(n+1));ra=r;
    r=r*sin(k*(2*n-1)*pi)/sin(2*k*n*pi);
    t=t-k*pi;
 end;
 R=ra/(2*sin(pi/nlim)),% radius of last polygon
 plot(S,'linewidth',4,'color','k')
```

Comment: $OP_nP_{n-1}$ is not a right triangle, in general.

Comment: @Intelligenci pauca Corrected now, Thanks !

Comment: Hello, @JaapScherphuis brought to my attention that the construction in the figure contradicts the definition of the sequence, so I deleted the figure. But you answered a follow up question that I will have, thank you.

Comment: Returned the figure, and changed the question to have 2 parts. Your answer tackles the 2nd part. Again thank you for your time, and apologies for the hassle.

Comment: I have added graphics (with the program which has generated them) and have given a better management (so I think...) of the limit case. I am still puzzled : is the limit of the radius finite or not ?

Comment: Looking at your figures,  $\forall n\ b_n > c_n$ seems to be the case, so $b_n$ may not converge.

Comment: A few things:

1. $\sin\left(\alpha_{n+1}\right) = \sin\left(\frac{n-1}{n+1}\pi\right)$

2. $\sin\left(\frac{n-2}{n+1}\pi\right) \neq \sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{n-1}\right)$

3. The equation in your Wolfram Alpha link is different from your Equation 3.

Though this doesn't matter because all 4 versions of Equation 3 converge to 0 at the limit.

Comment: Than you. I agree. Sorry for inconvenience. I had made, in an earlier step, a "parent error" that had "consequences on the children"... But the expressions in the Matlab program were the good ones... I fix the errors now.

Comment: The Wolfram Alpha expression looks the good one...

Comment: I agree that $b_n$ may not converge. But in this case, the divergence looks so lazy !... The problem remains open...

Comment: Since I'm looking for $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\operatorname{area}(b_n)$, we can use the formula for the area of a regular polygon. So $\operatorname{area}(b_n)=\frac{s^2n}{4\tan\left(\frac{π}{n}\right)}$, where $s$ is the side length. Plugging in $OP_n$ for $s$ and taking the limit gives us $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\operatorname{area}(b_n)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{4\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)}\prod\limits^n_{m=3}\left(\frac{\sin\left(\pi\frac{2m-1}{m(m+1)}\right)}{\sin\left(\pi\frac{m-1}{m+1}\right)}\right)^2$. This is a $0\cdot\infty$ indeterminate form.

Comment: Looking at its graph, $\operatorname{area}(b_n)$ seem to be $\mathcal{O}(\ln(n))$.

Comment: Caution : formula $\operatorname{area}(b_n)=\frac{s^2n}{4\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)}$  isn't good. The connection between sidelength $s_n$ and radius $R_n$ shouldn't involve the "tan" function but the "sin" function : it is $R_n=\frac{s_n}{2 \sin(\pi/(2n))}$. Moreover there is no "$n"$ in the numerator.